# What are the main OAuth advantages over a non-OAuth solution?

Tags: facebook, oauth

I've started reading about OAuth having seen it in the Facebook API and elsewhere. So I made it part of the way into reading the obscure specification text, and I'm just curious what is the advantage to all of this?

What are the advantages to using OAuth when one builds a new site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main advantage is one the security layer. Users don't need to give your site their Facebook user name and password in plain text, instead you get the OAuth token which can be revoked by the user at any time without changing the Facebook password.

Additionally not having to store Facebook and other passwords make your site a less attractive target for hackers.

Answer (score 1):

Linking into popular social media systems makes registrations very simple, which leads to more people taking the time (so to speak) to actually register on your site.

This is probably one of *the* most important aspects of a website, so making it quick and easy (not to mention the fact that some would go as far as to say a "trusted" login), is quite a good goal to keep in mind, as well as to realise.

`(Traffic == Life)` when it comes to a website.